# Are any quantum circuit can be translated into a matrix

Tags: quantum-gate

Given a quantum circuit, can we transform it into a Matrix. If the answer is yes - so practically, any quantum circuit is a presentation of matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quantum circuit on $n$ qubits corresponds to a $2^n\times 2^n$ unitary matrix.  This unitary matrix is unique up to a global phase (and up to other trivial operations such as a reordering of the rows and columns).

This is directly analogous to the classical case.  A classical circuit on $n$ bits corresponds to a truth-table of size $2^n$ - which is also unique up to a reordering of bits (although, classically, there is no global phase).

Circuits - classical or quantum - are often much more convenient to work with than the corresponding matrices, as they are a compact representation of the much larger matrix.