# What are the purposes of circuit gates in addition to matrix presentation

Tags: quantum-circuit

If quantum circuit gates can be presented as a matrix, are there any other qualities for the circuit gates except for a compact presentation of a matrix?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/35348/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/35347/55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical analog to your question, as far as I can see, is "what reasons, besides its simplicity and smaller size, do we use NAND-gates and NOR-gates to specify boolean functions?"  But we write such circuits when we actually want to implement the logic in silicon, e.g., with [VLSI-design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Scale_Integration).  The classical circuit corresponds to the etchings in silicon and the connections of metal for the transistors.  We do not directly implement the truth-table itself.

Similarly, quantum circuits are how quantum algorithms are intended to be run - we translate the $T$ gate or the $CZ$ gate, etc., to a sequence of microwave pulses or laser pulses, etc. The quantum circuit corresponds to the sequences of such electromagnetic pulses.  We do not directly implement the unitary matrix itself.